# Why oc get all and oc delete all command does not return/delete pvc and secrets

Tags: openshift

I am learning OpenShift (version 4.6).

Just trying to understand why `oc get all` doesn't return PVC and similarly `oc delete all --all` doesn't delete `pvc` and `secret`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this command in order to retrieve everything from a namespace (using oc v**4.10.13**):

```
$ oc get all,configmap,secret,pvc -n "${NAMESPACE}"
```

by design, `oc get all` does not return Secrets.

In order to read everything from a namespace, you would have to take the scoped namespace APIs and then perform a "oc get" on such returned APIs, like this:

```
oc get $(oc api-resources --namespaced=true --verbs=list -o name | awk '{printf "%s%s",sep,$0;sep=","}') -n "${NAMESPACE}" --ignore-not-found
```